# Start remote service through PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, button, lamp

Basically i want to pass different commands to the server through PHP `ssh2_connect` function. But i need to pass it through using different buttons for different commands, But unable to do it.

Below is my code with button:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('ipaddress', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');

if (isset($_POST['button'])) ssh2_exec($stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'systemctl stop apache2'));
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="button">Apache2</button
```

Code working without button:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('ipaddress', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'systemctl stop apache2');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Your codes not finished, it missing the rest of the HTML.
- Your nesting `ssh2_exec($stream = ssh2_exec(`, most likely a typo.
- Your stopping apache not starting it.

The following will get you started, hope it helps.

```
<?php
class ssh {

    public function __construct($ip, $user, $pass, $port = 22)
    {
        // connect
        $this->connection = ssh2_connect($ip, $port);
        ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $user, $pass);
    }

    public function exec($cmd = null)
    {
        // define streams
        $this->stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection, $cmd);
        $this->err_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($this->stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

        // get streams
        $this->output = stream_get_contents($this->stream);
        $this->error = stream_get_contents($this->err_stream);

        return $this;
    }
}

// define cmds
$commands = [
    'stop_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Stop Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl stop apache2'
    ],
    'restart_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Restart Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl restart apache2'
    ],
    'start_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Start Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl start apache2'
    ]
];

// handle post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $error = [];
    $result = '';

    // validate input
    if (empty($_POST['service'])) {
        $error = [
            'service' => 'Service type required!'    
        ];
    } elseif (!array_key_exists($_POST['service'], $commands)) {
        $error = [
            'service' => 'Invalid Service!'    
        ];
    }

    // run cmd - $result->output will have stdout, $result->error will have stderr
    if (empty($error)) {
        $ssh = new ssh('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password');
        $result = $ssh->exec($commands[$_POST['service']]['cmd']);
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?php if (!empty($error)): ?>
    <h3>Error</h3>
    <pre><?= print_r($error, true) ?></pre>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php foreach ($commands as $key => $command): ?>
    <button type="submit" name="service" value="<?= $key ?>"><?= $command['description'] ?></button>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</form>

<?php if (!empty($result)): ?>
<pre><?= print_r($result, true) ?></pre>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Perfect, It's working... I have added more services using above code.

Comment: np, glad it worked and helped. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: What can i do if i want to show the output of command that is execute through that code ?

Comment: as noted in the code `$result->output` will have stdout, `$result->error` will have stderr, dont confuse it with tty though your need to use pipes and websockets for that.

Comment: Right. Actually, Still it doesn't show the output.  I'm using php 5.6 Isn't the issue ?
But when i tested on php 7 then it shows the output.

Comment: @blaCkninJa If your not getting any output then check your error logs, as mentioned before your need the PECL extension installed https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2 - If its white screening that would most likely be it... If you want to use a better lib for SSH look into using https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib / [Example](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/2.0/examples.html)

Comment: Okay. If we do not use ssh. We can run locally. What would be the changes in the code ? Would you resend that code ?

Comment: I have wiped out ssh related code but script didn't work locally.

Comment: Open another question, your changes go beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I open new question with heading `PHP script wouldn't work`, Please look into it.

Comment: Could you please help me in this regard ?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322965/php-script-wouldnt-work/50323044?noredirect=1#comment87661941_50323044)