# PHP script wouldn't work

Tags: php, centos

Basically, I want to run below script locally in order start stop restart and get status of service. And it must show output of each command button. 
I am using php 5.6 in order to run this code.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
    // define cmds
    $commands = [
    'stop_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Stop Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl stop apache2'
    ],
    'restart_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Restart Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl restart apache2'
    ],
    'start_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Start Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl start apache2'
    ],
    'status_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Status Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl status apache2'
    ],
    ];

    // handle post
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $error = [];
    $result = '';

    // validate input
    if (empty($_POST['service'])) {
        $error = [
            'service' => 'Service type required!'    
        ];
    } elseif (!array_key_exists($_POST['service'], $commands)) {
        $error = [
            'service' => 'Invalid Service!'    
        ];
    }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <?php if (!empty($error)): ?>
    <h3>Error</h3>
    <pre><?= print_r($error, true) ?></pre>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php foreach ($commands as $key => $command): ?>
    <button type="submit" name="service" value="<?= $key ?>"><?= 
    $command['description'] ?></button>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </form>
   <?php if (!empty($result)): ?>
   <pre><?= print_r($result, true) ?></pre>
   <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: "wouldn't work" is too generic - please describe the exact problem / error.

Comment: why do you want to execute php instead of simple `systemctl start apache2` or any other command?

Comment: Shows no error anywhere neither in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @llyaBursov It's requirement for some purpose. And I can only archive it through this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
// handle post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$error = [];
$result = '';

// validate input
if (empty($_POST['service'])) {
    $error = [
        'service' => 'Service type required!'    
    ];
} elseif (!array_key_exists($_POST['service'], $commands)) {
    $error = [
        'service' => 'Invalid Service!'    
    ];
}
//you need add this line
else $result = $commands[$_POST['service']];
}
```

Comment: I have added but won't work and not stop service. Just show following in output:
`
Array
(
    [description] => Stop Apache2
    [cmd] => systemctl stop apache2
)`

Comment: You can call function shell_exec(command). (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely going to encounter permission issues because the web server user `www-data`, will **not** have permissions to restart the service.

So unless you allow that, it's not going to work. [The previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085326/start-remote-service-through-php/50085607?noredirect=1#comment87690207_50085607) which works is because you are logging in over SSH with root user.

Ok so if you did add allow `www-data` to restart the service, your code would be like the following. By using [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute the cmd.

```
<?php
// define cmds
$commands = [
    'stop_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Stop Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl stop apache2'
    ],
    'restart_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Restart Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl restart apache2'
    ],
    'start_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Start Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl start apache2'
    ],
    'status_apache' => [
        'description' => 'Status Apache2',
        'cmd' => 'systemctl status apache2'
    ],
];

// handle post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $error = [];
    $result = '';

    // validate input
    if (empty($_POST['service'])) {
        $error = [
            'service' => 'Service type required!'    
        ];
    } elseif (!array_key_exists($_POST['service'], $commands)) {
        $error = [
            'service' => 'Invalid Service!'    
        ];
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        exec($commands[$_POST['service']]['cmd'], $output, $status_code);
        if ($status_code === 0) {
            $result = 'Service restarted';
        } else {
            $error = 'Could not restart service! Status code: '.$status_code;
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php if (!empty($error)): ?>
    <h3>Error</h3>
    <pre><?= print_r($error, true) ?></pre>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php foreach ($commands as $key => $command): ?>
    <button type="submit" name="service" value="<?= $key ?>"><?= $command['description'] ?></button>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</form>

<?php if (!empty($result)): ?>
<pre><?= print_r($result, true) ?></pre>
<?php endif ?>
</form>
```

You will notice it will fail with `Could not restart service! Status code: 1` - Because `www-data` wont have permissions. You should read https://serverfault.com/questions/69847/linux-how-to-give-a-user-permission-to-restart-apache on how to fix that, also be aware it opens up the possibility of bad code constantly restarting apache and DOSing.

Personally, I would not do it directly as you want to do, but instead set up a task which is run by root user, and you place the operations (restart, stop etc) in a queue to run.

Hope that helps.